# What is the difference between PrivateObject vs PrivateType in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I was looking for approaches that could be used to access a static class which contains private static methods to unit test.

I came across `PrivateObject` and `PrivateType`, I do not understand what the difference between them is, and how you would decided to use either one.

BusinessLogic

```
public static Class BarLogic(){
  private static void FooBar(){
       //do something here
   }
}
```

API

```
public class FooService(){

BarLogic.FooBar();

}
```

Comment: Private object: "Allows test code to call methods and properties on the code under test that would be inaccessible because they are not public.", Private type: "Represents the type of a private class that gives access to private static implementations."

Comment: Where is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @Fabjan updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is whether you're accessing otherwise inaccessible instance members or static members.

In the example below, you would use `PrivateObject` to access `_someInstanceField`, and `PrivateType` to access `_someStaticField`.

```
public class SomeObjectWithInAccessibleMembers
{
    private int _someInstanceField;
    private static int _someStaticField;
}
```

Given that your test was in a separate assembly from this class (and therefore unable to to see its internal members) you could do this:

```
var privateObject = new PrivateObject(new SomeObjectWithInAccessibleMembers());
privateObject.SetField("_someInstanceField", 1);
Assert.AreEqual(1, privateObject.GetField("_someInstanceField"));

var privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(SomeObjectWithInAccessibleMembers));
privateType.SetStaticField("_someStaticField", 1);
Assert.AreEqual(1, privateType.GetStaticField("_someStaticField"));
```

I've never used this. I didn't even know about it. My first reaction is that it couples the test to the inner implementation of the class instead of testing its public methods. Then it couples it some more by using strings for member names, so the tests could break just by changing a member name.

On the other hand, I've worked in projects where a) I want to add unit tests, but b) I can't refactor to make it more testable. It's not my first choice but I might have a use for this. Thanks!

Comment: couldn't you access the SomeStaticProperty from PrivateObject?

Comment: Yes, using reflection. But that's what these classes prevent you from having to do.

Comment: Yes - so again I do not understand why you wouldn't just use PrivateObject rather than using PrivateType also?

Comment: You wouldn't use `PrivateType` unless you wanted access static members. If you do want to access static members then you could try doing it with `PrivateObject`, but you'd see that it's extra, unnecessary work so you'd probably just go back to `PrivateType`.

Comment: okay got it that makes sense